# Не отрабатывает ControlClick

Tags: autoit

```
; Запуск блокнота только так вызывается
Run('C:\kononov\Notepad++\notepad++.exe')

; Ожидание 5 секунд до появление окна блокнота
$hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad++]", "", 5)
If Not $hWnd Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Окно не найдено, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf

$hWnd1  =   WinGetHandle($hWnd, "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]")
If Not $hWnd1 Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Строчка окна не найдена,WinGetHandle, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf

; немогу понять почему не работает контролклик 
$hWnd3  = ControlClick($hWnd, '', '[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]',11, 12)
If Not $hWnd1 Then
    MsgBox(4096, 'Сообщение', 'Строчка не отработала, ControlClick, завершаем работу скрипта')
    Exit
EndIf
```

Программа запускается, но не нажимает на "новый".
При этом ошибки не выдает *(очень удивлен)*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Разобрался: [посмотрел первый ответ на вопрос в английском StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261218/autoit-controlclick-does-not-work).

Так было:

```
$hWnd3  = ControlClick($hWnd, '', '[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]',11, 12)
```

так стало:

```
$hWnd3  =ControlClick($hWnd, "", "[CLASS:ToolbarWindow32]", "Left", 1,11, 12)
```

Заработало :3